# How to fix two categories of UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors in Apex tests running in parallel?

Tags: unit-test, customsetting

I'm taking a look at running 300+ test classes in parallel again today. The main error - in about 5% of the test classes - was:

> UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record

which makes sense given the parallel execution. But the question is how to fix these. There seem to be 2 root causes...

**Contact locks**

The tests have Contact record inserts that had no Account specified and there is some underlying Account defaulting trigger logic. I am assuming that the lock is on the parent Account so that specifying a separate Account every time will fix. Does that seem right? It appears to work.

**Custom setting locks (and User locks)**

Some tests modify hierarchical custom settings to exercise some of our configuration options and so update the org-level custom settings at the same time, hence the locking problem. (The current User is also modified in a smll number off cases.) No easy solution comes to mind for these: is there a good pattern for this case? There is this known issue on the subject [Document known issue with UNABLE TO LOCK ROW when testing Custom Settings](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kyuqAAA).

Presently trying this ugly code for the custom setting upserts in the tests:

```
/**
 * When tests are run in parallel, UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors occur where tests update the same custom setting.
 * This class aims to get around that by retrying over a longish time.
 */
public class Retry {

    public static void upsertOnUnableToLockRow(SObject sob) {

        // Only ever seen one retry needed this should be lots
        Integer n = 20;
        Integer sleepMs = 100;

        Exception lastException;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            try {
                upsert sob;
                return;
            } catch (DmlException e) {
                if (!e.getMessage().contains('UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW')) {
                    throw e;
                }
                lastException = e;
                sleep(sleepMs);
            }
        }

        throw lastException;
    }

    private static void sleep(Integer ms) {

        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < start + ms) {
            // Throw away CPU cycles
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SeeAllData=true? Have you tried row-locking statements (e.g. `SELECT ... FROM CustomSetting__c FOR UPDATE`)?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Not using `SeeAllData=true`. Also seems as if the custom setting rows already have an implicit `for update`;

Comment: Keith - for the custom settings, why not use a selector pattern for these and then mock the selector results rather than directly trying to update via DML the custom settings?

Comment: Hi @cropredy, Yeah with 20-20 hindsight a good idea, but lots of code touching the objects and fields directly so significant work/risk to do such a refactor.

Comment: So sorry --  all of our org's custom metadata and custom settings are behind selector layers so they can be mocked; the issue you stated in OP happens to us with creating User records to test runAs (and mocking through selector layers doesn't help here)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @cropredy - agree it is the right way to go. I'm nearly there with the above changes - 2 failing test classes out of 300+ and 8-minute test run instead of 2 hours. But probably fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that a mocking solution is the better way to go, below is the class I ended up using to workaround the custom setting UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors. A bit more info here too https://force201.wordpress.com/2019/05/14/embracing-apex-parallel-testing/.

```
/**
 * When tests are run in parallel, UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW errors occur where tests update the same custom setting.
 * This class aims to get around that by retrying.
 * Can also be applied to ordinary SObjects.
 */
public class Retry {

    // Typically zero or one retry so this should be plenty unless there is some kind of deadlock
    private static final Integer TRIES = 50;
    private static final Integer SLEEP_MS = 100;

    public class RetryException extends Exception {
    }

    public static void upsertOnUnableToLockRow(SObject sob) {

        upsertOnUnableToLockRow(new SObject[] {sob});
    }

    public static void upsertOnUnableToLockRow(SObject[] sobs) {

        if (sobs.size() == 0) return;

        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Exception lastException;

        for (Integer i = 0; i < TRIES; i++) {
            try {
                SObject[] inserts = new SObject[] {};
                SObject[] updates = new SObject[] {};
                for (SObject sob : sobs) {
                    if (sob.Id != null) updates.add(sob);
                    else inserts.add(sob);
                }
                insert inserts;
                update updates;
                return;
            } catch (DmlException e) {
                // Immediately throw if an unrelated problem
                if (!e.getMessage().contains('UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW')) throw e;
                lastException = e;
                sleep(SLEEP_MS);
            }
        }

        Long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
        throw new RetryException(''
            + 'Retry.upsertOnUnableToLockRow failed first id='
            + sobs[0].Id
            + ' of '
            + sobs.size()
            + ' records after '
            + TRIES
            + ' tries taking '
            + (finish - start)
            + ' ms with exception '
            + lastException
        );
    }

    private static void sleep(Integer ms) {

        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < start + ms) {
            // Throw away CPU cycles
        }
    }
}
```